# Can you return a numpy scalar with numba?

Tags: numpy, numba

Numpy scalars returned by a function decorated by (n)jit are casted to python float/int types per default. This came as a surprise to me, as it breaks the return contract. I am curious if this can be overruled. Any help or explanation is much appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb
from numba import uint64

@nb.njit
def foo():
    return np.float32(1)

@nb.njit(uint64())
def bar():
    return np.float32(1)

float64_not_np_float32 = foo()
int64_not_np_uint64 = bar()

print(type(float64_not_np_float32))
print(foo.nopython_signatures)
print(type(int64_not_np_uint64))
print(bar.nopython_signatures)

--> <class 'float'>
--> [() -> float32]
--> <class 'int'>
--> [() -> uint64]
```

Expected behaviour:

```
def foo():
    return np.float32(1)

np_float32 = foo()
print(type(np_float32))
--> <class 'numpy.float32'>
```

Comment: This is the goal of the Numba wrapping function. AFAIK this cannot be overruled. You can convert the result back manually, possibly using another wrapper. I do not see any advantage of doing this : Numpy floats are much slower and less flexible than CPython floats. The Wrapper does the conversion because there is no distinction in Numba between `np.float64` and `float` (the two are native 64-bit floats) while this is not true in CPython where both are objects of different types. The automatic conversion is faster than doing it manually in CPython because it is compiled.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response Jérôme.